# compute $P(X_4 = 2,X_3 \leq 2,X_2 \leq 2,X_1 \leq 2|X_0 = 1)$ where we are given that transition probabilities $P_{11}, P_{12}, P_{21}, P_{22}$.

Tags: probability, markov-chains

This is an example from Introduction to probability models by Ross.

Consider a Markov chain with states 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and suppose
that we want to compute $P(X_4 = 2,X_3 \leq 2,X_2 \leq 2,X_1 \leq 2|X_0 = 1)$

where we are given that transition probabilities $P_{11}, P_{12}, P_{21}, P_{22}$.
$$
P_{11} = 0.3; P_{12} = 0.3;
P_{21} = 0.1 ;P_{22} = 0.2
$$

My Solution:

$$
P(X_4 = 2,X_3 \leq 2,X_2 \leq 2,X_1 \leq 2|X_0 = 1)\\
= P(X_4 = 2|X_3 \leq 2) \times P(X_3 \leq 2| X_2 \leq 2)\times P(X_2 \leq 2| X_1 \leq 2) \times P(X_1 \leq 2|X_0 = 1) \\
=(\sum_{i=1,2}P_{i,2}) \times (\sum_{i,j=1,2}P_{i,j})^2 \times (\sum_{j=1,2}P_{1,j})\\
=(0.3+0.2) \times (0.3+0.3+0.1+0.2)^2 \times (0.3+0.3) \\
=0.243
$$

But this is not the right answer. Can anyone figure out what is wrong with this solution?

Comment: In your solution the first equality is not correct. You can get sight on that by writing $P(A\mid B)$ as $P(A\cap B)/P(B)$ on both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P\left(X_{4}=2,X_{3}\leq2,X_{2}\leq2,X_{1}\leq2\mid X_{0}=1\right)P\left(X_{0}=1\right)=P\left(X_{4}=2,X_{3}\leq2,X_{2}\leq2,X_{1}\leq2,X_{0}=1\right)$$

The RHS of this can be written as:$$P\left(X_{4}=2\mid X_{3}\leq2,X_{2}\leq2,X_{1}\leq2,X_{0}=1\right)P\left(X_{3}\leq2\mid X_{2}\leq2,X_{1}\leq2,X_{0}=1\right)$$$$P\left(X_{2}\leq2\mid X_{1}\leq2,X_{0}=1\right)P\left(X_{1}\leq2\mid X_{0}=1\right)P\left(X_{0}=1\right)$$

Then dividing both sides by $P(X_0=1$ we find that: $$P\left(X_{4}=2,X_{3}\leq2,X_{2}\leq2,X_{1}\leq2\mid X_{0}=1\right)=$$$$P\left(X_{4}=2\mid X_{3}\leq2,X_{2}\leq2,X_{1}\leq2,X_{0}=1\right)P\left(X_{3}\leq2\mid X_{2}\leq2,X_{1}\leq2,X_{0}=1\right)$$$$P\left(X_{2}\leq2\mid X_{1}\leq2,X_{0}=1\right)P\left(X_{1}\leq2\mid X_{0}=1\right)$$

You have a sortlike result where e.g. the factor $P\left(X_{4}=2\mid X_{3}\leq2,X_{2}\leq2,X_{1}\leq2,X_{0}=1\right)$ is abusively replaced by $P\left(X_{4}=2\mid X_{3}\leq2\right)$.

Comment: This is a markov chain. So, can't you replace $P\left(X_{4}=2\mid X_{3}\leq2,X_{2}\leq2,X_{1}\leq2,X_{0}=1\right)$ by $P\left(X_{4}=2\mid X_{3}\leq2\right)$?

Comment: That works for equalities like: $P(X_4=2\mid X_3=2, X_2\leq 2)=P(X_4=2\mid X_3=2)$, but not for inequalities like $P(X_4=2\mid X_3\leq2, X_2\leq 2)$. The extra condition $X_2\leq2$ will have an impact on which of the values $1,2$ will be taken by $X_3$.

Comment: This is something new for me. You mentioned that The extra condition $X_2 \leq 2$ will have an impact on which of the values 1,2 will be taken by $X_3$. Can you show this or give me some reference?

Comment: Suppose for instance that $P_{12}=1$. Then $P(X_4=3\mid X_3\leq 2,X_2=1)=P_{23}$ because $X_2=1$ "forces" $X_3$ to take value $2$. But $P(X_4=3\mid X_3\leq 2)=P_{13}+P_{23}$.

Comment: What you learned stays valid, but I made a mistake in my former comment (sorry for the confusion). There  $P(X_4=3\mid X_3\leq2)$ does not equalize the *sum* $P_{12}+P_{23}$ (as I said wrongly. Shame on me!), but it equalizes the *weighted sum* $P_{13}P(X_3=1\mid X_3\leq2)+P_{23}P(X_3=2\mid X_3\leq2)$. Here $P(X_3=i\mid X_3\leq2)=P(X_3=i)/P(X_3\leq2)$ for $i=1,2$.